# I need to create a button in the list in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {
    fetchRecipes,
} from '../../store/actions';
import './BeerRecipes.css';

const BeerRecipes = ({recipesData, fetchRecipes}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchRecipes();
    }, [])

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        alert('aaa');
    }

    return (
        <div className='beer_recipes_block'>
            <div className='title_wrapper'>
                <h2 className='title'>Beer recipes</h2>
            </div>
            <div className='beer_recipes'>
                <ul className='beer_recipes_items'>
                        {
                            recipesData.recipes.map(recipe =>
                                <button className='btn' onContextMenu={handleClick}>
                                    <li className='beer_recipes_item' id={recipe.id}>
                                        <p>
                                            'Beer {recipe.name}, has its tagline
                                            <b>'{recipe.tagline}'</b>, firstly, was brewed in {recipe.first_brewed}
                                            {recipe.description}
                                        </p>
                                        {/*<img src={recipe.image_url} alt={recipe.name}/>*/}
                                    </li>
                                </button>
                            )
                        }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        recipesData: state.recipes
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchRecipes: () => dispatch(fetchRecipes()),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeerRecipes);
```

help me to create button in the 'li' tag with contextmenu event. I need it to delete each separate unit of the list. Could you please create that function also. I created handleClick to check if the event works. I would be very grateful for the help

Comment: would like to remove from the `state.recipes` that given recipe?

Comment: yes, whole entire button element